# Avoid search on element values or attributes with fnFilter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've noticed that the search function not only looks for the visible content but also on the attributes of the elements in the table.

Here's a living example of it with a checkbox and its value: (search for "*demo*", or "*second*")
http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/510/

In my case, i have checkboxes in the datable and they have classes, data-types and values. When the user wants to use the search feature, it also look for all those attributes and that's not really what a filter should use.

Example of my checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="demo" class="lookForThis">
```

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

See the link below it should help you out.  It lists a couple different ways to skin this cat.

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/807/how-to-filter-excluding-certain-columns-or-filter-only-on-text-content-not-html-tags-within-cells/p1